# WPF Listview/Gridview setting selected item when combobox is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox, selecteditem

I'm having issues using a GridView as a ListView's View, what I want to do is fire an event when a user makes a selection from a combobox within the Gridview and pass the selected item within the event.

- My first issue is that when the user clicks the combobox within a row, the row isnt selected (meaning the selecteditem stays null unless they click elsewhere first). Is there a clean way to do this without trying to catch mouse clicks or anything?
- Secondly theres no selectionchangecommited event on a WPF combobox, is there a cleaner way to check if a user has manually selected an option other than checking if the combobox is enabled?

Thanks

Comment: did you find the answer for it?

Comment: Link is broken can I get solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'solved' my issue by using the WPF Toolkit grid (http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) and a series of selected items, which is probably a cleaner solution anyway.
Doesn't explain the behavior of the GridView, which is to me unusual

Original link has died, believe this to be the one https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing a similar behavior. My hypothesis is that one or more layers of the DataTemplate of each item in the list is swallowing the RoutedEvent that should have resulted in a new selection. Is it possible to, in a generic way, tell the items in the DataTemplate that they should never stop the event from bubbeling or tunneling further, without having to override every focus-triggering event handler in code behind?